# Hibernate class design, persisting List and HashMap

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

In my application, I have two classes: `Activity` and `User`. The relationship among them are:

- An activity can have multiple user. I have a field `List<User>` for this purpose in `Activity` class.
- An user can belongs to multiple activities and in each activity he/she can have a specific role. I have refined a `Map<String, String>` in `User`, where the `key` of this `Map` is the `activityId` and the value is `roleId`. I don't have any `Role` table, as there are only four predefined Roles.

I am unable to understand should there be any `ManyToOne` or `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Activity`. Or should I simple store the whole `List<User>` object along with `Activity` and `Map<String, String>` with `User` in database. If so, how can I store a whole `List` and a `Map`.

Any pointer would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first think about how the design would be in database. If I understand correctly, you would have 3 tables:

- User
- Activity
- Participation

where Participation would have  a foreign key to a user, a foreign key to an activity, and a role.

So I would map that simply as

- User has a OneToMany with Participation
- Activity has a OneToMany with Participation

And of course you can make these two associations bidirectional.

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean the `Role` by Participation?

Comment: No, I mean an entity which has a ManyToOne with User, a ManyToOne with Activity, and a role (which should be implemented as an enum). So a participation is an entity which models the fact that a given user participates to a given activity with a given role.

Answer (score 1):

`User <-> Activity` is `many to many`. Navigability can be `bidirectional`- choice is yours.
You also need a `UserActivityMap` object with three attributes (userId,ActivityId, roleId). RoleId can be an enum or an id of a RoleObject. In case of latter, you can define a lookup table and map RoleObject to that.